# difference using async vs return new Promise

Tags: node.js, next.js, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to call an async utility function from NextJS API page, but gets undefined.
The console prints the following when I go to localhost:300/api/hello

```
result =  undefined
```

File 1: api/hello.js

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  getCountries().then(result=>{
    console.log('result = ', result);
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok', data: result.data });
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log('error = ', err);
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', error: err });    
  })
}
```

File 2: utils/getCountries.js

```
const getCountries = async () => {
    var response = [];
    var params = { action: "get_countries", ...authKey }
    axios.get(APIFOOTBALL_URL, { params: params })
        .then((result) => {
          response = [...result.data];
          return response;
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
}

export default getCountries;
```

Changing the getCountries function to the following works, but I don't understand why.
Isn't async returning a promise as well?
If I have to write it in the async/await method, how should I go about?

File 2: utils/getCountries.js

```
const getCountries = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        var response = [];
        var params = { action: "get_countries", ...authKey }
    
        axios.get(APIFOOTBALL_URL, { params: params })
            .then((result) => {
              response = [...result.data];
              resolve(response);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject;
            });
    })
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in the first version. The default return value for a function in `undefined`. You'd need something like `return axios.get(...`

Answer (score 2):

In your first example of `getCountries`, you are returning a promise of nothing (undefined), whereas in the second example, you are returning a promise of the response.

What happens in your first example is, `axios.get` runs, but then nothing is really stopping the function from returning. The entire point of calling `.then` on `axios.get` is so that whatever is in the `.then` callback gets executed after the promise is resolved. Otherwise you could have just written the code you're writing in `.then` after the `axios.get` call as usual, which you CAN do, if you use await. Using `await` would stop the code execution until the promise is either resolved or rejected (which is why you should only use `await` in a try-catch block.

If your first example is refactored as follows:

```js
const getCountries = async () => {
    const params = { action: "get_countries", ...authKey }
    try {
        const result = await axios.get(APIFOOTBALL_URL, { params: params });
        const response = [...result.data];
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("An error occurred while trying to fetch countries: ", err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

you end up blocking the execution of the code after the `axios.get` call until that promise is resolved or rejected.

In short, the reason your first example doesn't work, is because your function returns `undefined` (implicitly as there's no return statement in your first example) after the `axios.get` call. Nothing stops it from returning, and so the promise your first example is returning is always resolved with `undefined` value.

The reason your second example DOES work, is because when you're manually returning a promise, it is always pending until you manually resolve it with `resolve(response);` or `reject`.

If that doesn't help, think about it this way -> In the calling code, when you do `getCountries.then`, The `.then` part only executes when the promise is resolved. The the value it is resolved with is passed to the callback (which you use as `result`). In your first example, `getCountries` immediately resolves with a value of `undefined`, so your callback gets the `undefined` value, whereas in the second example, the promise that `getCountries` returns is pending until `resolve` is called in your code, which only happens after your API request promise resolves (since you're calling it in the `.then` callback of `axios.get`).

Also, in your first example, when you do `return response;` in the `.then` part of `axios.get`, you are returning from the callback function of `.then`. This does not return from the `getCountries` function. Maybe that is causing you to think this should work, but doesn't.

Your first example can also be made to work if you do this:

```js
const getCountries = async () => {
    const params = { action: "get_countries", ...authKey }
    return axios.get(APIFOOTBALL_URL, { params: params })
        .then((result) => {
          const response = [...result.data];
          return response;
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
}
```

because now, `getCountries` is returning a promise of the response, instead of just returning a promise of `undefined`.

Lastly, as @jfriend00 mentioned, there is no reason for a `.catch()` that only throws the error again. The point of catch is to do something with the error (log it or handle it). The way you are using `.catch()` right now will have the same behaviour as not using it at all.

Comment: thank you. finally dawned on me that `.then()` does not block. always thought they work the same as async/await

Answer (score 1):

In an `async` function, you must either `await` your promise or you must return it. Without one of those, nothing actually waits for that promise or communicates back any result from it.  Since the point of using `async` is to be able to use `await`, here's what that would look like:

```
const getCountries = async () => {
    const params = { action: "get_countries", ...authKey }
    const result = await axios.get(APIFOOTBALL_URL, { params: params });
    return result.data;
}
```

Or alternately, you can just return the promise and don't need `async`:

```
const getCountries = () => {
    const params = { action: "get_countries", ...authKey }
    return axios.get(APIFOOTBALL_URL, { params: params }).then(result =>{
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

A couple other notes about your code:

1. There is no reason to use `var` any more.  Use `let` or `const` instead in all modern Javascript.
2. There's no reason to copy the data with `response = [...result.data];`.  You can just do `return result.data`.
3. Your last code block is considered a promise anti-pattern. You never want to wrap an existing promise (the one return from the `axios.get()` call) with a manually created promise.  It's just not necessary and often creates problems with error handling which indeed you have because you didn't call `reject(err)` properly.
4. There's no reason for a `.catch()` that only does `throw err` unless you also have some other code in that `.catch()` (such as logging the error).